# How to use Python to reach an external web page

Tags: python

I have external web page like www.3thpart.com/folder/test.jsp?page=IND

This page uses "TOKEN" to authenticate there is no login(authentication) but for each different request web site creates a token. 
I use this page in my company by some users lots of time. To get easier and save time What I need to do is to collect result in backand then display the result in a HTML page in from of the users. 
I tried python with Visual studio. I am comfused. is it possible to give me advise that the way i have to follow. I mean I am trying to understand the logic of this situation.

Thanks in advance
C.A.

**UPDATE:**

```
import requests

url = 'https://subdomain.domain.com.tr/folder/main.jsp?page=ID'
payload = {
    'Requested': 'fieldValue',
    'Cmdd ': 'fieldValue',
    'TOKEN': '',
    'LANG': 'tr',
}

s = requests.Session()
response = s.post(url, data=payload)
outfile =open( "/Projects/Gib/test.txt","w")
response.encoding = 'UTF-8'
outfile.write(response.text)
```

Comment: What have you tried? Have you at least googled for e.g. `python http request token authentication`? A lot of results, many of them here on SO.

Comment: The page is like that. I couldn't create a request even an error :(
 it should be a http(s) request, souldn't it? I tried to what i have tried
https://subdomain.domain.com.tr/folder/main.jsp?page=ID
 
FIELDS: 
Requested
Cmdd
TOKEN
LANG